# Convert dictionary values to list using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

Following code giving me 'Evaluation of lambda expressions is not valid in the debugger'. 
Please suggest where I am doing wrong from below -

```
List<MyFieldClass> lstFiedls;
lstFiedls = objDictionary.Select(item => item.Value).ToList();
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is the type of `objDictionary`?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You don't need to use Linq to get the values. The `Dictionary(TKey, TValue)` has a property that holds the values, [`Dictionary(TKey, TValue).Values`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx):

```
var fields = objDictionary.Values.ToList();
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that the `ToList()` method of the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` class is actually an extension method in `System.Linq`.  However, since the `ValueCollection` implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`, you can add the values to a list without converting.

Comment: Also worth noting that you can use the `AsEnumerable()` Linq extension method to get an `IEnumerable` instead of a `List`. `objDictionary.Values.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @RubberDuck is Values.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator(); more performant than Values.ToList().GetEnumerator();?   I am curious?

Comment: It’s just lazy @GregoryWilliamBryant. It won’t load the entire list as a copy into memory. A couple of benchmarks might be interesting.

Answer (score 5):

You will get a compiler error simply trying to convert a dictionary's values to a list with ToList():

```
        Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        var result = dict.Values.ToList();
```

Unless you include "using System.Linq" in your file.

Answer (score 2):

With C# 7 it is possible to use tuples, which makes this conversion much simpler and you can have both the key and the value in the list.

```
   var mylist = new List<(Tkey, TValue)>(dic.Select(x => (Tkey, TValue)));
```

full example

```
       Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dic.Add(1, "test1");
        dic.Add(2, "test2");
        dic.Add(3, "test3");

        
        var mylist = new List<(int, string)>(dic.Select(x => (x.Key, x.Value)));

        foreach (var myItem in mylist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"int val = {myItem.Item1} string = {myItem.Item2}");
        }
```

result

```
int val = 1 string = test1
int val = 2 string = test2
int val = 3 string = test3
```